# How can I view the DNS Cache in Big Sur?

Tags: macos, big-sur, dns

I would like to be able to view the DNS Cache on Big Sur. I tried using:

```
$ sudo dscacheutil -cachedump 
                                                                                                              
Unable to get details from the cache node
```

One other method I tried was to send:

```
sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder
```

while viewing the log with:

```
log stream --predicate 'process == "mDNSResponder"' --info
```

As I understand it, this used to kick mDNSResponder to spit out the cache information. However, what shows up in the log is:

```
 Sending SIGINFO to mDNSResponder daemon is deprecated. To trigger state dump, please use 'dns-sd -O', enter 'dns-sd -h' for more information
```

If I issue `dns-sd -O`, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo dns-sd -O                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

XPC service returns error, description: State dump is only enabled in internal builds
```

How can I view the DNS Cache?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do here is disable SIP, dump the mDNSResponder process memory, and attempt to grep through the memory dump for dns strings.

1. Disable SIP and boot up the unprotected system.
2. `sudo lldb --attach-pid $(pgrep -f '^/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder$')`
3. process save-core
4. ctrl-d to quit
5. run the following perl script, passing it the filename 'core' to extract appropriate content (Some of the output will be gibberish, but the dns entries should be in the list.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Check for file argument
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
if (not defined $filename) {
    die "Usage: $0 filename\n";
}

# Read the entire file into a string.
open(my $fh, '<:raw', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
my $data = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close($fh);

# Filter out non-printable characters, keeping printable ones including spaces and newlines.
$data =~ s/[^[:print:]\n\r\t]//g;

# Use a hash to store matches to ensure uniqueness.
my %matches;

# Now, filter for domain-like strings, avoiding those ending with .framework or .dylib and starting with com.apple.
# Also avoid consecutive periods.
while ($data =~ m/(?<!\.)(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}(?!\.)/g) {
    my $match = $&;
    unless ($match =~ /\.framework$|\.dylib$/ || $match =~ /^com\.apple/) {
        $matches{$match} = 1; # Store each unique match in the hash.
    }
}

# Sort the keys of the hash (which are the unique matches) and print them.
foreach my $match (sort keys %matches) {
    print "$match\n";
}
```

If that isn't practical, I suggest looking for solutions that capture dns requests as they happen over the wire. [Zeek](https://docs.zeek.org/en/master/logs/dns.html) is one solution I know works well.  When running, it should create a dns.log file with the requests.  There are other paid EDR solutions that can tie dns requests back to the originating process.